# Proper Case in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have this sentence "i want to buy bananas" across column 'Bananas' in Big Query.

I want to get "I Want To Buy Bananas". How do I it? I was expecting PROPER(Bananas) function when I saw LOWER and UPPER but it seems like PROPER case is not supported?

DZ

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> October 2020 Update:

BigQuery now support **[INITCAP](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#initcap)** function - which takes a STRING and returns it with the first character in each word in uppercase and all other characters in lowercase. Non-alphabetic characters remain the same.

So, below type of fancy-shmancy UDF is not needed anymore - instead you just use

```
#standradSQL
SELECT str, INITCAP(str) proper_str
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Below example is for BigQuery Standrad SQL

```
#standradSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION PROPER(str STRING) AS (( 
  SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTR(w,1,1)), LOWER(SUBSTR(w,2))), ' ' ORDER BY pos) 
  FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(str, ' ')) w WITH OFFSET pos
));
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'i Want to buy bananas' str
)
SELECT str, PROPER(str) proper_str
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

result is

```
Row str                     proper_str   
1   i Want to buy bananas   I Want To Buy Bananas
```

Answer (score 1):

I expanded on Mikhail Berlyant's answer to also capitalise after hypens (`-`) as I needed to use proper case for place names. Had to switch from the SPLIT function to using a regex to do this.

I test for an empty string at the start and return an empty string (as opposed to null) to match the behaviour of the native UPPER and LOWER functions.

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION PROPER(str STRING) AS (( 
  SELECT 
    IF(str = '', '',
      STRING_AGG(
        CONCAT(
          UPPER(SUBSTR(single_words,1,1)), 
          LOWER(SUBSTR(single_words,2))
        ), 
        '' ORDER BY position
      )
    )
  FROM UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(str, r' +|-+|.[^ -]*')) AS single_words
  WITH OFFSET AS position
));

WITH test_table AS (
  SELECT 'i Want to buy bananas' AS str
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'neWCASTle upon-tyne' AS str
)

SELECT str, PROPER(str) AS proper_str
FROM test_table
```

Output

```
Row str                     proper_str   
1   i Want to buy bananas   I Want To Buy Bananas  
2   neWCASTle upon-tyne     Newcastle Upon-Tyne
```